# Conditions on continuity of wavefunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

If I have a wavefunction $\Psi(x,t)$ in one dimension; am I always justified in the claim that:

$$\frac{d^2\Psi}{dxdt} = \frac{d^2\Psi}{dtdx}$$
It would seem that $\Psi(x,t)$ would need to satisfy certain a certain continuity constraint (of second derivatives?) for this to be true, which I'm not sure is always justified.

---

Context: I'm trying to prove that $d\langle p \rangle / dt = \langle - \partial V / \partial x \rangle$, and so far I have:
$$ \frac{d}{dt} \langle p  \rangle = \frac{\hbar}{i} \int \frac{d\Psi^*}{dt} \frac{d\Psi}{dx} + \Psi^* \frac{d^2\Psi}{dtdx} dx$$
By applying product rule. If I could swap the order of differentiation on the second term, then I figured out that I can substitute in Shrodinger's equation (and it's conjugate); and everything works out fine; I'm just not sure if I'm fully justified in swapping the order of differentiation.

Comment: The wavefunctions are continuous functions of $x$, *except* at points where there is an infinite discontinuity in the potential: infinite wells and $\delta$-wells are examples where there is a discontinuity.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem#General_example

Comment: Like ZeroTheHero said, the wavefunction is continious except at points where the potential is discontiue. Or you could rephrase that as, every physical sensible wavefunction will allow you to swap those derivativs.